# Salesforce reports - how to disable smart totalling (or is there a workaround)?

Tags: reporting, custom-object, report-builder

As you will see in the picture, I have three columns in a report from two objects.  The appointment object contains an APPID and the Matter Code contains the other information.  I am "trying" to total the column Average duration but it removes duplicates when I try and summarise with sum.

Essentially I want to see the total time spent on Appointments for each directorate.  I have tried summarising the column and adding a formula field but they all produce the same result:

Can anyone help or is this a design problem, is a "roll up summary" something I should be considering?

In the example below I would expect the top directorate to be 2.5 and the bottom directorate to be 7.5.  I will also add that each Appointment will only have 1 Matter Code related to it.

[image]

Edit, I think the feature "Smart Totalling" is what is causing my headache...is there a way to disable it for specific reports?

Comment: Thread to vote if you think disabling smart tottalling is a good idead: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000Bqn1AAC

Comment: You should never trust the results in preview mode ;) and no, you cannot disable that

Comment: Thanks, still the same once the report is ran thouhg.  Is there any work around or better design?

Comment: see 'power of one' discussions that may be useful to you

Comment: i've tried to take a look but as the duration value changes it didn't work...